# How to clear out state variables in React?

Tags: reactjs

Since support for `replaceState` is removed and `setState` does [shallow merging](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-are-merged), is it possible to remove all state variables and update the state by adding new variables as in the cases below without mutating(`this.state`) the state directly?

```
// let's say this.state is { foo: "123", bar: "456", baz: "789" }

// case 1 - this.state is cleared out, all state variables are removed
// this.state is {}

// case 2 - this.state is cleared out and new variable(s) introduced
// this.state is { qux: "lately introduced state variable" }
```

Answer (score 4):

> is it possible to remove all state variables and update the state by adding new variables as in the cases below without mutating(this.state) the state directly

I could be wrong, but I don't think this is possible.

When you set up state for your component, you're establishing a model for your component to adhere to, so wiping out the attributes of your components state (rather than updating them) breaks the principles of state management in react. I believe this is in part the motivation for removing replaceState

see https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3236 for more information

Think about the difference between ice and water (the key difference being  temperature). Temperature never disappears from the equation, it just changes value, and the water responds accordingly. Stateful react components operate under similar principles.

By establishing a model for your component we create a contract between the 2 and can make changes to our UX in a predictable manner.

You can of course update these values to  be null, undefined, 0, false, etc but you cannot remove them from the signature of your initial state once it is created.

You could easily accomplish this with nested state however:

```
this.state = { foo: { bar: { baz: 'buzz' } } }

// remove state.foo.bar
this.setState({ foo: {} })
```

Comment: Yeah I have the same thought with you that it is almost not possible.Just out of curiosity wanted to see if there is still something that makes it possible. Thanks for sharing your thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

Well, no. As far as I know you are not able to go around this but with `this.state = {}` as you already know. However, I can't imagine case where you want to clear your state completely, but I can imagine you want to reset the state sometimes.  This could be done by following

```
class Cmp extends React.Component {
  getClearState() {
    return {
      foo: undefined;
      bar: undefined;
      baz: undefined;
      qux: undefined;
    }
  }

  caseOne() {
    this.setState(this.getClearState())
  }

  caseTwo() {
    this.setState({
      ...this.getClearState(), 
      qux: 'my QUX',
    })
  }

  render() {}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you do something like this for case 1:

```
this.setState(Object.assign({}, {}));
```

And this for use 2:

```
this.setState(Object.assign({}, {qux:'blah'}));
```

Comment: Not working since these are also shallow merging as `Object.assign({}, {})` yields to `{ }` and `Object.assign({}, {qux:'blah'})` yields to `{qux: 'blah'}` which result in `this.setState( { });` and `this.setState( {qux: 'blah'} );` respectively.